# Accidental double loops in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, leaflet

I've built an application wherein you can select a table in a database and then show the data on a Leaflet map. The data has a matching legend.

I want my application to accept a variety of datasets and be able to display them on the map, with minimal programming alterations. This is a new demand and I've altered my previous code, but it's not optimal.

The code I have now loops through the dataset to assign a color to certain value, but it also loops through the dataset to extract the unique values so that I can use them in the legend.

This causes my application to have a loop in a loop, generating unnecessary calculations. This is no problem with a small dataset, 19 records x19 is doable, but 8062x8062...

The for loop in the `getColor()` function is the problem. I tried relocating the for loop to a new function (getColor v2), but I always end up missing `arrayMetKetens`. I think `getColor()` runs before `getArray()` can return it's value, but because a lot of functions start running once I select a table, I can't really force `getArray()` to return it quicker. Or is there?

**Code for adding color to markers/polygons:**

```
window["mapDataLayer"] = L.geoJson(geojson_dataTable, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        var markerStyle = { 
            fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.Fastfoodketen),
            color: "#696969",
            fillOpacity: 0.6,
            opacity: 0.9,
            weight: 1,
            radius: 8
        };
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, markerStyle);
    },

     style: function (feature){
         if(feature.geometry.type === 'MultiPolygon'){
             var polygonStyle = {
            fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.Naam),
            color: "grey",
            weight: 5,
            opacity: 1
            };
         }
         else{
             return null;
         }
         return polygonStyle;
     }
}).addTo(map);
```

**getColor function:**

```
function getColor(keten) {
    checkTable();
    var ketens = [];

    for(i=0;i<(geojson_dataTable.features).length;i++){
        ketens = ketens.concat(Object.byString(geojson_dataTable, 'features['+i+'].properties.'+featureVoorSorteer))
    }
    console.log(ketens);
    arrayMetKetens = (jQuery.unique( ketens ));
    var i = arrayMetKetens.indexOf(keten);

    if (i !== -1) {
        return arrayKleur[ i ];
        } 
    else {
        return '#999999';
    } 
}
```

**getColor v2:**

```
function getArray(){
    var ketens = [];
    for(i=0;i<(geojson_dataTable.features).length;i++){
        ketens = ketens.concat(Object.byString(geojson_dataTable, 'features['+i+'].properties.'+featureVoorSorteer))
        console.log(ketens);
    }
    arrayMetKetens = (jQuery.unique( ketens ));
    return arrayMetKetens.
}

function getColor(keten) {
    checkTable();
    getArray();
    yMetKetens.indexOf(keten);
    if (i !== -1) {
        return arrayKleur[ i ];
        } 
    else {
        return '#999999';
    } 
    console.log("hij doet het")
}
```

Comment: I think you should ask a new question if you have a new problem. That said: if your problem is like you expect it to be, it should be easy to confirm by adding some `console.log()`s at various places in your code to check if the order of execution is like you expect it to be.

Comment: Your right, will rollback and make a brand new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firs of all, if you don't mind me commenting on the JS programming style, this code is... well... far from perfect :-) Particularly the indirect usage of global variable makes it tricky to read. I'll try to give it a shot and suggest something that doesn't imply "rewrite the whole thing".

I'm going to follow the usage of global variables in functions even though it's commonly considered to be an anti-pattern.

First thing - if the code you submitted as "getColor v2" is the ACTUAL code then there's an obvious bug in it:

```
function getColor(keten) {
    checkTable();
    getArray();
    //yMetKetens.indexOf(keten);<-- looks like partialy copied code :-)
    // SHOULD BE THIS:
    var i = arrayMetKetens.indexOf(keten);
    if (i !== -1) {
        return arrayKleur[ i ];
        } 
    else {
        return '#999999';
    } 
    console.log("hij doet het")
}
```

With that one fixed we still have the call to `getArray()` every time we call `getColor()`. But first let's have a look at slightly improved version of `getArray()`:

```
function getArray(){
    var ketens = [];
    //for(i=0;i<(geojson_dataTable.features).length;i++){
    //    ketens = ketens.concat(Object.byString(geojson_dataTable, 'features['+i+'].properties.'+featureVoorSorteer))
    //    console.log(ketens);
    //}
    //THE CODE ABOVE CAN BE SIMPLY EXPRESSED AS
    for(i=0;i < geojson_dataTable.features.length;i++){
       ketens = keten.concat(geojson_dataTable.features[i].properties[featureVoorSorteer])
    }
    //lets use global variable arrayMetKetens explicitly 
    window.arrayMetKetens = jQuery.unique( ketens );
    //return arrayMetKetens <-- we never use the return value of the function anyway...

}
```

now we can slightly modify our function `getColor()`:

```
function getColor(keten) {
    checkTable();
    //getArray(); <--REMOVE CALL TO getArray()
    var i = window.arrayMetKetens.indexOf(keten);//<-- explicit use of global variable we initialise in getArray()
    if (i !== -1) {
        return arrayKleur[ i ];
        } 
    else {
        return '#999999';
    } 
    console.log("hij doet het")
}
```

And the last thing we have to do is to call `getArray()` as soon as we have `geojson_dataTable` object at hand. The code you submitted doesn't have that part so let'd put it here:

```
getArray();//<-- calling getArray() here will initialise (once) the array arrayMetKetens 
           //    which then can be used in the function getColors()
window["mapDataLayer"] = L.geoJson(geojson_dataTable, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        var markerStyle = { 
            fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.Fastfoodketen),
            color: "#696969",
            fillOpacity: 0.6,
            opacity: 0.9,
            weight: 1,
            radius: 8
        };
```

That was fun! :-) I hope it helps... ;-)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to sift through my code, I'm far, far from a pro at JS, as you can see.. :p. Learning while trying I guess. I implemented the changes you suggested, and made one more small change to `getColor()`. The call to `checkTable()` is placed under the call to `getArray()`. Everything is shown on the map now, although the large dataset is a bit slow. Also, the large dataset has no color (strange?) and the matching legend doesn't seem to work correctly. Ill edit my question with the new findings. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I made a new question, if you could take a look I really appreciate it! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38100320/large-dataset-not-using-js-leaflet-functions-correctly

Comment: I'll have a look later today if that's ok :-)