# Large dataset not using JS/Leaflet functions correctly

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I've built an application wherein you can select a table in a database and then show the data on a Leaflet map. The data has a matching legend.

I want my application to accept a variety of datasets and be able to display them on the map, with minimal programming alterations. This is a new demand and I've altered my previous code, but it's not optimal.

One of my datasets is pretty large, 8000+ record with multipolygons and many column. When adding this dataset to the map, it takes some time to load (not really a problem). The matching legend isn't working quite how it should. It returns colors, which is good, but it's showing all values instead of the unique values. All the other datasets, which are smaller, or have points instead of polygons, work perfectly fine.

As you can see, the legend on the left doesn't pick the unique values, whereas the legend on the right works fine. For some reason `arrayMetKetens` is not filled with unique values, but rather it's filled with all the values. When I `console.log(arrayMetKetens)`, it just gives all the values. **Why is this?**

The color will repeat because these come from an array wherein the colors are defined. I'm still looking for a way to "repeat" the array, but this has a lower priority.

[image]

**arrayKleur:**

```
arrayKleur = ["#b15928", "#6a3d9a", "#ff7f00", "#e31a1c", "#33a02c", "#1f78b4", "#a6cee3", "#b2df8a", "#fb9a99", "#fdbf6f","#b15928", "#6a3d9a", "#ff7f00", "#e31a1c", "#33a02c", "#1f78b4", "#a6cee3", "#b2df8a", "#fb9a99", "#fdbf6f"];
```

**Code for legend:**

```
function legenda(){
    var HTMLlegenda = '<h4>Legenda</h4>'

    // if arrayMetKetens is empty => default legenda text 
    if (arrayMetKetens.length == 0 ){
        HTMLlegenda += '<p>Selecteer een tabel in de "Advanced selection" tab om de legenda weer te geven</p>'

        $("#tab1").html(HTMLlegenda);
    }
    // if arrayMetKetens is filled => generate legenda
    else{

        $("#tab1").html(arrayMetKetens);

        for(ii = 0; ii < arrayMetKetens.length; ii++){

            HTMLlegenda += '<i id="background" style="background:'+arrayKleur[ii]+'">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>'+arrayMetKetens[ii]+'</br>'
        }
        $("#tab1").html(HTMLlegenda);
    }
}
```

**Code for adding color to markers/polygons:**

```
getArray();
checkTable();
window["mapDataLayer"] = L.geoJson(geojson_dataTable, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        var markerStyle = { 
            fillColor: getColor(feature.properties[featureVoorSorteer]),
            color: "#696969",
            fillOpacity: 0.6,
            opacity: 0.9,
            weight: 1,
            radius: 8
        };
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, markerStyle);
    },

     style: function (feature){
         if(feature.geometry.type === 'MultiPolygon'){
             var polygonStyle = {
            fillColor: getColor(feature.properties[featureVoorSorteer]),
            color: "grey",
            weight: 5,
            opacity: 1
            };
         }
         else{
             return null;
         }
         return polygonStyle;
     }
}).addTo(map);
```

**getColor function:**

```
function getColor(keten) {
    var i = window.arrayMetKetens.indexOf(keten);
    if (i !== -1) {
        return arrayKleur[ i ];
        } 
    else {
        return '#999999';
    } 
}
```

**checkTable variable:**

```
function checkTable(){
    var e = document.getElementById("slctTable");
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    if(strUser == "fastfood_groningen"){
        featureVoorSorteer = "Fastfoodketen"
    }
    else if(strUser == "wijkindeling_groningen"){
        featureVoorSorteer = "Naam"
    }
    else if(strUser == "panden_vbo_loppersum"){
        featureVoorSorteer = "Bouwjaar"
    }
    else {
        featureVoorSorteer = "";
        console.log("featureVoorSorteer is leeg, geen juiste selectie 'select table'")
    }
    return featureVoorSorteer;
}
```

**getArray function:**

```
function getArray(){
    var ketens = [];
    for(i=0;i < geojson_dataTable.features.length;i++){
       ketens = ketens.concat(geojson_dataTable.features[i].properties[featureVoorSorteer])
    }
    window.arrayMetKetens = jQuery.unique( ketens );
}
```

Comment: Don't we need to see where `arrayMetKetens` is defined?

Comment: @ snkashis, hmm forgot one, will edit my question.

Comment: This one is a real puzzler. :-) It seems to be a problem in function `getArray()`. The behaviour you describe could happen if the line this line doesn't get executed: `window.arrayMetKetens = jQuery.unique( ketens );`. That on the other hand could happen if the `for` loop causes an exception after executing few iterations. Do you get any errors in JS console?

Comment: It gives my errors whatsoever unfortunately, so it gives nothing to work with.

Comment: Could you please add 2 lines at the end of your `getArray()` function: `console.log('selected property'+featureVoorSorteer); console.log(window.arrayMetKetens)`. Then from your select box try to select  'Fastfoodketen' then 'Bouwjaar' than 'Fastfoodketen' again and check if the console has all the expected output  - the name of the selected property and the array - is the last array for Fastfoodketen unique? Also, could you pleas change all the occurrences of `arrayMetKetens` inside `legenda()` to `window.arrayMetKetens`?

Comment: When adding the two lines of code, I get a ReferenceError: `featureVoorSorteer is not defined` on the line of `console.log('selected property'...)`. The application stops and nothing is shown on the map. This is strange, because I use `featureVoorSorteer` in `ketens.concat(...)` too, and I never get an error there. When I remove the two console.logs, everything works fine again. When only running `console.log(window.arrayMetKetens)`, the console gives back: `["1980", "2012", "1975", "1980", "2013"....5632 more`, but this was always the case. As you can see, values aren't unique in the array.

Comment: When implementing @snkashis suggestion, your 2 lines of code work. The last array of 'Fastfoodketen' is perfeclty unique. It's really strange, the same function but different results.

Answer (score 2):

I think your sequence of events here is a bit mis-ordered. You call checkTable() after getArray()

```
getArray();
checkTable();
```

yet `getArray` depends on `featureVoorSorteer` being available.
Not only that, `getArray` seems to depend on a global `featureVoorSorteer`
Why don't you do something like

```
var featureVoorSorteer = checkTable();
getArray(featureVoorSorteer);
```

to avoid using globals?

Comment: With your solution the console.logs suggested by Rafal Zajac work. Seems that at least something is working better now.